# K8s on Digital Ocean - unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, digital-ocean

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL database in a Kubernetes cluster on Digital Ocean. To do so, I've created a `StatefulSet` and a `Service`. And to set up a volume in order to persist data, I took a look at the  [Add Block Storage Volumes tutorial](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/add-volumes/). My k8s configurations for the `StatefulSet` and `Service` are down below.

I simply used a `volumeClaimTemplates` . The storage class `do-block-storage` exists in the cluster (`volumeBindingMode` is set as `Immediate`). The `pv` and the `pvc` are successfully created.

> A volumeClaimTemplates that is responsible for locating the block storage volume by name csi-pvc. If a volume by that name does not exist, one will be created.

But my pod falls in a **CrashLoopBackOff.** I'm getting:`0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. Back-off restarting failed container`

It is also worth saying that my cluster only has one node.

Can any please help me understand why? Thanks

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres-db
spec:
  serviceName: postgres-db
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
      app: my-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: db
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:13
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: csi-pvc
        - mountPath: "/config"
          name: postgres-config-map
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-config-map
          configMap:
            name: postgres-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: csi-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: do-block-storage

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-db
  labels:
    role: db
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    role: db
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  type: ClusterIP
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set `volumeBindingMode` to `WaitForFirstConsumer` ?

Comment: @mario it is not possible to change the do-block-storage StorageClass. But I managed to fix my problem by adding the pvc first instead of using volumeClaimTemplates

Comment: If you've found the solution, please share it as an answer to your question and mark it as accepted. It can also serve other people who may encounter a similar issue in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by adding the pvc first instead of using volumeClaimTemplates